# Backbone.js -- Can't access another model's methods from a model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Given these snippets (hopefully complete enough for this question)...

ModelA.js (has many modelBs):

```
ModelBs = (function(_super) {
    ModelB.prototype.bWithName = function(name) {
        return this.find(function (b) {
            return b.name == name;
        });
    }
})(Backbone.Collection);

return ModelA = (function(_super) {
    ...
    ModelA.prototype.initialize = function() {
        this.modelbs = new ModelBs(this.modelbs, {});
    };

    ModelA.prototype.bWithName = function(name) {
        return this.modelbs.bWithName(name);
    };

    return modelA;
})(BaseModel);
```

ModelC.js (has one modelA):

```
ModelC.prototype.toString = function(opts) {
    ...
    console.log(this.modelA); // defined...
    console.log(this.modelA.modelBs); // defined...
    console.log(this.modelA.bWithName("foo")); // undefined
    ...
}
```

**In ModelC.js, why are `this.modelA` and `this.modelA.modelBs` defined, but `this.modelA.bWithName()` undefined,** and how can I fix it?

This works: `this.modelA.modelBs.first()`.

This returns undefined: `this.modelA.modelBs.where({name:"foo"})`.

In the web console, this works: `modelZ.modelAs.first().bWithName("foo").attributes`.

Are accessors or methods in general not available through other models?

Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah. The method was in fact available, but the strict equals (`===`) was killing the search. In one instance I was trying to search with the wrong typeof name.

Thanks for the input though!